# Regular Expression to Match Items That May Not Have an Ending Delimiter

Tags: php, regex

I need to match both **test1** and **test3** in the sample URL below:

```
http://www.domain.com/:test1/test2/:test3
```

This regex isn't doing it:

```
(:.*?/?)
```

Any thoughts?

Comment: You can use a lookahead to check if there is a `/` or if it's the end of the line. [demo](http://regex101.com/r/hV9pS0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one will do:

```
$str = 'http://www.domain.com/:test1/test2/:test3';
preg_match_all('~:\w+~', $str, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Output:

```
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(2) {
    [0] =>
    string(6) ":test1"
    [1] =>
    string(6) ":test3"
  }
}
```

Explanation:

```
~    starting delimiter
:    a colon
\w   a *word* char
+    as many of them as possible
~    ending delimiter
```

Answer (score 1):

is that what you are looking for?

```
/:([^\/]+)/i
```

Answer (score 1):

I think that this might work for you :

```
$string = 'http://www.domain.com/:test1/test2/:test3';
preg_match_all('#:.*?/|:.*#i', $string, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
```

Answer (score 0):

There's a little tutorial which explains how regex engines interpret ? and * here:

http://www.regex-engine.com/demo.html#repetition